# Cognito Group Limitations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a limit to how many users can belong to a single group in AWS Cognito User Pools?

I did not see a limit specified in the [Quotas in Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) but I read [a blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/design-highly-scalable-user-groups-aws-cognito-hamish-sadler/) that claims there is a limit of 1k users per group. It also said that there is a limit of 1k groups per account, which is incorrect, so I don't trust it.

My application has an internal RBAC system so I was thinking of just assigning all users to the same group. Currently each user that gets created also creates a group to which they are the only member. The IAM roles and groups getting created for each group have identical IAM policies(authorization is handled by the application's internal RBAC) but I need to know if this will scale.

If there is a limit on users per group that is lower than the limit on users per pool I can design around that, but I won't if the main bottleneck is users per user pool.

Comment: Did you get any insights into this approach? I'm fixing to take this same route - each user belonging to their own group but also belonging to other general groups. I'll use general groups as Roles in C# dotnet Authorize statements and the initial group for aws IAM role to access their resources. This could also be used for the temporary sharing of resources between users.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the limits and quotas on [Cognito Quotas page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html)

| Resource | Quota | Adjustable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users per user pool | 40,000,000 | Yes |
| Groups per user pool | 10,000 | No |

Comment: I linked that exact document in my original question. It still does not answer my question, which I believe is a valid question that isn't answered definitively by that doc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).